# Creating Multiplie Pie Charts in a same page using d3 with JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, pie-chart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

    #radiobutton {
        font: 20px sans-serif;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 380px;
        color: green;
    }
.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -mox-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}
#tooltip.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
    #tooltip p {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }



</style>

<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Adult_Mortality_rate of Whole Population</strong>
    </p>
    <p><span id="value">100</span></p>
</div>
<div id="radiobutton">
<form>

   <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="country" > country</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="value" checked> values</label>
</form></div>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var m = 10,
      r = 100,
      z = d3.scale.category20c();

    var width = 960,
        height = 500,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(50)
        .innerRadius(0);



    var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(0)
                        .outerRadius(50 + 50);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) { return d.Overall; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

The below code is use to draw a pie chart but I would like to create another similar pie chart in the same page using a different column value in the JSON file that I have. Example: For the first pie chart, I am using the Overall column but the second pie chart that I would like to create would use the Under70 column in the JSON file. Is there anyway for me to create both pie charts in the same page?

```
    d3.json("data.json", function (error, data) {


        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Overall = +d.Overall;
            d.Under70 = +d.Under70;

        });

        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc")

    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select("#tooltip")
            .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
            .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .select("#value")
            .text(d.data.Overall);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
        // Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);;
    });


        g.append("path")

            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.data.gender);

            })
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            d3.select(this).transition()
               .duration(1000)
               .attr("d", arcOver);

        })
                .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                    d3.select(this).transition()
                       .duration(1000)
                       .attr("d", arc);
                });

        g.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")

             .attr("text-anchor", "middle") //center the text on it's origin
      .style("fill", "Purple")
      .style("font", "bold 12px Arial")
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.gender });

    });
</script>
```

This is my JSON file:

```
[{"country":"Singapore","gender": "Male", "Overall":"1234", "Under70": "1224"},
 {"country":"Singapore","gender": "Female", "Overall":"4567","Under70": "5678"}]
```

Comment: Yes, we can draw any no.of pie charts, wait for a moment I'm working on it. I'll give you a fiddle.Okay

Comment: Here is the fiddle for you,If it is not fulfilling ask what you exactly needed.
http://jsfiddle.net/r6xxE/

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple diagrams on the same page the easiest way is to create different svgs in your page within your script and then point the pie charts to the different svgs.